# Tag:data-dictionary

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The [data-dictionary](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-dictionary) tag has the following description:

> A data dictionary, or metadata repository, as defined in the IBM Dictionary of Computing, is a "centralized repository of information about data such as meaning, relationships to other data, origin, usage, and format."

The tag is used for 5 questions that are all related to a language 'dictionary' (i.e [German-English translation](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/german-english-dictionary)). I'd suggest replacing [data-dictionary](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-dictionary) with [dictionary](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dictionary) for these 5 questions, and then removing the [data-dictionary](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-dictionary) tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that in 4 of the 5 questions, [data-dictionary](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-dictionary) is used incorrectly. [Metadata standards and best practices for data dictionaries for CSV files/data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/157/70) is the only question that uses the tag appropriately.

However, since many users seem to misunderstand the tag, and only one question would remain using it, I'd go ahead and remove the tag anyway. The [metadata](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metadata) tag (with currently 9 questions) should be a suitable replacement for now.